# Circuit to disable a PNP with 3.3V IO when emitter voltage is 4.5V

Tags: analog, bjt, pnp

I am working on a circuit which should be active when my MCU is powered off and 3.3 is not available.

So basically the idea is that the pnp (Q2) should conduct untill i disable it by setting the MCU pin High. I realized that the Emitter voltage is higher than the IO voltage so this will not work. I have attached a simplified circuit of my design.

My question is; what is the best way to implement a circuit that allow me to "override" the Pull-down resistor (R4) with my IO pin?

Thanks in advance!

[image: simplified circuit]

Answer (score 1):

Two diodes in series create a handy 1.2V drop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOoIqm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edit: If you need it to work with varying voltages higher than 4.5V, you will need a few more transistors, i.e. something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsZKaZ.png)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This would work as long as my emitter voltage is not larger than 4.5V. Is there any way to implement this with an additional transistor so that I can manage larger emitter voltages as well?

Comment: @aleli91 I've edited my post and added a circuit that should work for that purpose!

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I am looking for.